# Combine taskbar shortcut and window icons

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons

I've noticed on my windows 7 PC that some pinned shortcut icons on the taskbar do not combine with their application window icon.

For example, the normal behaviour is shown with Google Chrome when pinned to the taskbar *and* open, the taskbar has just the one Chrome icon, with a square around it to indicate there is a window open.

But for another application (TI Code Composer Studio [Eclipse] in this case) does not - the window icon and the shortcut icon are two separate icons on the task bar.

How can I force these separate icons to assume the normal, combined, behaviour?

I have tired setting the taskbar button property to "Always combine, hide labels" with no luck

[image: taskbar with combined and separate shortcut and window icons]

Comment: This depends entirely on the app. There's no easy way to override the default behaviour AFAIK.

Comment: Have you tried with pinning the launched program and removing the launch shortcut?

Comment: @AEonAX Hey, that worked! Thanks! If you'd like to make that an answer I'll do the needful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the Program you are opening itself

It seems to have some weird behaviours that windows cannot understand (opening renamed process and closing itself for example)

If this really bugs you you might contact the App developer or remove it from your task bar.